# Press a button on an application programmatically on Linux Wayland

Tags: linux, automation, wayland

I have a GUI application, and I want to programmatically get a way to press one of its buttons.

Especially, one that updates the application, so I can implement some kind of auto-update for it.

I found out about xdotool and it seems to be possible to do it with it. But, its Wayland variant, ydotool can't do it.

Is it possible to do on Wayland?

Comment: Did you try something like this? https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/